# Exclude a field from django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the following serializer, I have a nested serializer [`ContainerSerializer`] field and I want to exclude a field from (container)`ContainerSerializer` but I don't want any change in `ContainerSerializer`. How can I do that?

```
class BLcontainerMergedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    container = ContainerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = BLcontainer
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Create another serializer say `BLContainerSerializer` and exclude fields there. Then use this in your `BLcontainerMergedSerializer`. Hope this helps.

```
class BLContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        exclude = ('field1', )


class BLcontainerMergedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    container = BLContainerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = BLcontainer
```

Comment: *Although the question doesn't fall into this trap - it's worth noting that you can't have both the fields and exclude attributes on a Serializer class.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fields meta property:

```
class BLcontainerMergedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    container = ContainerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = BLcontainer
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

Reference: [Django REST docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include)

Comment: this adds fields from `BLcontainer`, not from `container`