# How can I hide fields in auto-generated schemas, or define schemas explicitly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, drf-yasg

I am using [`drf-yasg`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io) ([Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org) - Yet Another Swagger Generator) to generate docs for my RESTful API, but it's not doing exactly what I want. I thought that setting `read_only` and `write_only` attributes to `True` would hide fields from the documentation as they are omitted from request and response bodies, but this is not the case. I don't see any examples of defining schemas within a decorator, or even just hiding a field, but if I can learn how to do one of those things, I'll be in good shape.

Let's go with a basic example: user login.

```py
# serializers.py
class TokensSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Serializes access and refresh tokens for responses to a logged-in user.
    """
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=64, write_only=True)
    access = serializers.CharField(max_length=4096, read_only=True)
    refresh = serializers.CharField(max_length=4096, read_only=True)
    
    # ...


class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes username, email, password, and tokens to allow for logging in.
    """
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'tokens']

    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=254, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=8, max_length=64, write_only=True)
    tokens = TokensSerializer(read_only=True)

    # ...
```

These serializers generate `Tokens` and `Login` models respectively, which are defined in the following *.json* and *.yaml* formats:

```json
{
  "definitions": {
    "Tokens": {
      "required": ["username"],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "username": {
          "title": "Username",
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 64,
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "access": {
          "title": "Access",
          "type": "string",
          "readOnly": true,
          "maxLength": 4096,
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "refresh": {
          "title": "Refresh",
          "type": "string",
          "readOnly": true,
          "maxLength": 4096,
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "Login": {
      "required": ["username", "password"],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "username": {
          "title": "Username",
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 64,
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "email": {
          "title": "Email",
          "type": "string",
          "readOnly": true,
          "maxLength": 254,
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "password": {
          "title": "Password",
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 64,
          "minLength": 8
        },
        "tokens": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Tokens"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```yaml
definitions:
  Tokens:
    required:
      - username
    type: object
    properties:
      username:
        title: Username
        type: string
        maxLength: 64
        minLength: 1
      access:
        title: Access
        type: string
        readOnly: true
        maxLength: 4096
        minLength: 1
      refresh:
        title: Refresh
        type: string
        readOnly: true
        maxLength: 4096
        minLength: 1
  Login:
    required:
      - username
      - password
    type: object
    properties:
      username:
        title: Username
        type: string
        maxLength: 64
        minLength: 1
      email:
        title: Email
        type: string
        readOnly: true
        maxLength: 254
        minLength: 1
      password:
        title: Password
        type: string
        maxLength: 64
        minLength: 8
      tokens:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Tokens'
```

However, these are not suited for every request or response body, and I would like to either define the schemas explicitly, or use the existing ones with fields omitted. I have no idea how to implement the latter, but here's my attempt at the former, which results in an error:

```py
class LoginView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    View for taking in an existing user's credentials and authorizing them if valid or denying access if invalid.
    """
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            201: {
                'schema': {
                    'description': 'TODO',
                    'required': ['username', 'email', 'tokens'],
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'username': {
                            'title': 'Username',
                            'type': 'string',
                            'maxLength': 64,
                            'minLength': 1
                        },
                        'email': {
                            'title': 'Email',
                            'type': 'string',
                            'readOnly': True,
                            'maxLength': 254,
                            'minLength': 1
                        },
                        'tokens': {
                            '$ref': '#/definitions/Tokens'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    def post(self, request):
      # ...
```

```
Failed to load API definition.

Errors
 
Fetch error
Internal Server Error http://localhost:8000/api/v0-alpha/?format=openapi
```

The only other option I can think of is to create a serializer for every schema, but that seems more laborious than necessary. Any thoughts?

Comment: I open to using a different generator if this one is lacking in features, so feel free to post answers that use another one. Any suggestions?

Comment: This thread helped me to solve similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366605/exclude-a-field-from-django-rest-framework-serializer

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ref_name` of the nested serializer's Meta class to `None` as answered here:
https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/239#issuecomment-442629230

Comment: That will hide *every* instance of the serializer, correct? I want to hide it only in some cases (as well as other fields) or define the schema without it.